# Vue3 не отображaет данные при использовании sfc (script setup)

Tags: vue.js, vue3

Проблема в заголовке. Код:

```
<template>
    <pre>
      {{ apiData }}  // Отображает на странице: []
    </pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, onBeforeMount } from 'vue'
import axios from "axios"

import { TestData } from '@multi-app/general-types'

let apiData = ref<TestData>([])

onBeforeMount( async () => {
  await axios.get<TestData[]>('http://localhost:3333/api/')
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)  // [{id: 1, text: '123'}]
    apiData = res.data
  })
})

</script>
```

Интерфейс типа `TestData`:

```
export interface TestData {
  id: number;
  text: string;
}
```

Подскажите, как правильно задать переменную в таком варианте реализации и поместить в нее данные из axios запроса?

Comment: @0xdb и Ma3rX указали что проблема в заголовке (что это вообще значит???), но на самом деле мой способ вполне рабочий, просто я случайно перезатирал данные в ref, т.е. нужно изменить на let apiData = ref<TestData>(), а в then поместить значение в value, т.е. apiData.value = res.data. И все будет работать

Comment: _указали что проблема в заголовке_, а когда вы правку принимаете, вы ее читаете? Вы автор и за вами последнее слово. Нажав "править", есть возможность отката до любой версии изменений, вы можете ее воспользоваться.

Comment: @0xdb у меня не было функции не принимать правку, только одна единственная кнопка. сейчас я могу внести изменения в правку, но вносить такого рода правку от авторитетных (сужу по рейтингу) пользователей тоже весьма странно

Comment: _указали что проблема в заголовке_, весьма странно, должна быть кнопка - отклонить.  Теперь есть функция отката (см. выше). Рейтинг тут не причём, вы автор, за вами последнее слово. Я хотел отклонить правку, но всплыло предупреждение, что правка уже принята. Мне ничего не осталось, как ее немного улучшить.

Comment: @0xdb хорошо, благодарю за отзывчивость и разъяснение